# Jsonp giving headers error in Angular 5

Tags: angular, jsonp

I am using angular 5 **HttpClientJsonpModule** for working with jsonp. I am following [this](http://orizens.com/wp/topics/upgrading-to-angular-5-using-httpclient-jsonp-with-parameters/) article. I have imported required files in app.module.ts file and also in my service.

This is my url (with callback appended at the end).

```
validPrimaryCurrencyCodes = "https://api.independentreserve.com/Public/GetValidPrimaryCurrencyCodes&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK"
```

And here I am using http.jsonp call to getting data

```
getValidPrimaryCurrencyCodes() : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.jsonp(this.urls.validPrimaryCurrencyCodes, 'callback');
}
```

It is giving me following error in console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have no `?` in your url, but also you don't need to add the callback parameter to the URL anyway. It's added automatically as you can see from the url in the error, so you should just remove it.

Comment: So, what do I write as second param while calling. I have removed &callback=JSONP_CALLBACK from url but still it is giving me second cors error as shown in image.

Comment: Does the server at api.independentreserve.com actually support JSONP? You know the server has to print out excecutable Javascript like `callback ( {"data": "The JSON data"});` instead of plain JSON

Comment: And I just checked, no it doesn't. It returns JSON, so I'm afraid unless they provide some other endpoint for JSONP, you can't do JSONP requests to that api.

Comment: Can you recommend what alternative I can use in angular 5 for working with these apis? How chrome extension logic works, can I use that logic in angular?

Comment: You can't get around cross domain protection.

Comment: You could however host a proxy server to route your calls through.